# Producer and Consumer with Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, pecs

I have this method to retrieve the objects which are instance of a given class:

```
public class UtilitiesClass {

    public static final Collection<Animal> get(Collection<Animal> animals, Class<? extends Animal> clazz) {
        // returns the Animals which are an instanceof clazz in animals
    }
...
}
```

To call the method, I can do something like this:

```
Collection<Animal> dogs = UtilitiesClass.get(animals, Dog.class);
```

That is good, but I would also like to be able to call the method in these two ways:

```
Collection<Animal> dogs = UtilitiesClass.get(animals, Dog.class);
```

or

```
Collection<Dog> dogsTyped = UtilitiesClass.get(animals, Dog.class);
```

What I mean is that I want to be able to store result of the method in a Dog Collection or in an Animal one, because `Dog.class` extends `Animal.class`

I was thinking in something like this:

```
public static final <T> Collection<T> get(Class<T extends Animal> clazz) {
    // returns the Animals which are an instanceof clazz
}
```

But it does not work. Any hint?

Edit:
Finally, using @Rohit Jain answer, this is the solution when you call to the UtilitiesClass method:

```
Collection<? extends Animal> dogsAnimals = UtilitiesClass.get(animals, Dog.class);
Collection<Dog> dogs = UtilitiesClass.get(animals, Dog.class);
```

Comment: So, to be sure what you exactly want, you want to have a function that extracts all `Dog`s out of an `Animal` collection? And that collection should be of type `Collection<Dog>`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you have to make the method generic. And the bounds should be given while declaring the type parameter:

```
public static final <T extends Animal> Collection<T> get(
                   Collection<Animal> animals, Class<T> clazz) {
}
```

But, while adding the `animal` from `animals` collection to a new `Collection<T>`, you would have to cast it back to `clazz` type. You would need [`Class#isInstance(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method, and also [`Class#cast(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Comment: But, if I do that, Eclipse says to me: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collection<Dog> to Collection<Animal>, when I call to the method with Collection<Dog> dogs = UtilitiesClass.get(animals, Dog.class)

Comment: @Manuelarte I updated the answer. Was missing something. Now it would work.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible in Java 8 without using `Class<T>`, however still **may** involve typecasting. A version that does not involve typecasting is also possible, but a bit more verbose:

```
public interface Animal {
    public void makeSound();
}
```

---

```
public class Dog implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Waf");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Cat implements Animal {
    @Override
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("Miauw");
    }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Utils {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T_IN, T_OUT> Collection<T_OUT> getBySubType(Collection<T_IN> input, Predicate<T_IN> predicate) {
        return input.stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .map(element -> (T_OUT)element)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static <T_IN, T_OUT> Collection<T_OUT> getBySubTypeSafe(Collection<T_IN> input, Predicate<T_IN> predicate, Function<T_IN, T_OUT> function) {
        return input.stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .map(function)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestProject3 {
    private void init() {
        List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        animals.add(new Dog());
        animals.add(new Cat());
        animals.add(new Dog());
        animals.add(new Cat());
        animals.forEach(Animal::makeSound);

        System.out.println();

        Collection<Dog> dogs = Utils.getBySubType(animals, animal -> (animal instanceof Dog));
        dogs.forEach(Animal::makeSound);

        System.out.println();

        Collection<Cat> cats = Utils.getBySubTypeSafe(animals, animal -> (animal instanceof Cat), animal -> (Cat)animal);
        cats.forEach(Animal::makeSound);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProject3().init();
    }
}
```

Output:

> Waf
>   Miauw
>   Waf
>   Miauw
>
> Waf
>   Waf
>
> Miauw
>   Miauw

What it does, is, in `getBySubType` resp `getBySubTypeSafe`:

- Obtain as input `Collection<T_IN>`.
- Filter everything based on the `instanceof` predicate.
- In one version cast it to `T_OUT`, in our version use a `Function<T_IN, T_OUT>` to explicitely safely cast it.
- Return the `Collection<T_OUT>`.

Answer (score 0):

The argument type should be generic wildcard to accept input collections of any subclass of Animal.

```
public static final <T extends Animal> Collection<T> get(
        Collection<? extends Animal> animals, Class<T> clazz ) {
    Collection<T> filteredAnimals = new ArrayList<T>();
    for ( Animal animal : animals ) {
        if ( clazz.isInstance( animal ) ) {
            filteredAnimals.add( clazz.cast( animal ) );
        }
    }
    return filteredAnimals;
}
```